# Variables not updating in Flutter API call in FlutterFlow

Tags: django, flutter, flutterflow

[image: API definition]

I am defining an API call on button action (refer to the attached image) in FlutterFlow.

The thing is in the API call, JSON variables are going empty.

[image: JSON body going empty]

[image: Network tab]

I am also attaching the action related to textbox onChange.

[image: Action on username textbox]

[image: Action on password textbox]

[The application can be run here](https://app.flutterflow.io/run/jgNt0MaEQZxM1reJXHSf)

I have defined the backend API as follows:

`@api_view(['POST'])
def login_member(request):
data = request.body

```
# Decode the bytes into a string
data_str = data.decode('utf-8')

#splitlist = str(data).split('&')

#username_raw = splitlist[0].split('=')[1]
#password_raw = splitlist[1].split('=')[1]

data_dict = json.loads(data_str)

#parsed_body = QueryDict(data.decode('utf-8'))

#print("Parsed body in login_members is ",parsed_body)

username = data_dict['username']
password = data_dict['password']

print("Username final is ",username)
print("Password final is ",password)

if username == '' or username == None or password == '' or \
    password == None or ((username == '' or username == None) and \
                         (password == '' or password == None)):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/token/", data=
                        {
                            'username': username,
                            'password': password
                        })

return Response(data=res.json())`
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone is able to help and let me know the solution to the issue

I tried changing the body of API call from Form-encoded to JSON.

I changed my backend settings in python.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of the same issues on a multi page form. Only random variables post to the data base (Supabase) through a get API in Buildship. API in buildship works perfect with the database.

I am going to try the textbook on change to see if that helps mine.

I can get one field to pass info with what I have using this as the action on the "submit" button.
[submit flow using json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzQtm.png)